# Entity Framework Core set User.RoleId does not automatically associate the related Role entity to the user.Role

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using the latest Entity Framework Core Database First approach with MySql.

The Database Provider is

> Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

So I assume that all generated code should be find, the issue should be in my own code.

I use database scaffolding function to generate my database entity classes and dataContext class.

There are 2 tables: User, Role.

Relationship: 1 user belongs to 1 role.

When creating an user, I pass in a role id and set its roleId like:

```
user.RoleId = roleId;
db.SaveChanges();
```

I was expecting to see the user.Role with value after the SaveChanges(), but this does not happen.

Am I missing something?

**Update**

I tried to retrieve the Role entity by searching against the roleId and then I assign the retrieved Role entity to user.Role and save:

```
var role = GetRoleById(user.RoleId);
user.Role = role ?? throw new AppException("User Role is not found");
```

Yet, after SaveChanges() and then the next time when an API request comes in to retrieve a user, the user still only has value in user.RoleId but user.Role is null.

**Update 2**

User Class:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("user");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.ApartmentId)
                .HasName("user_apartment_fk_idx");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.RoleId)
                .HasName("roleId");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                .HasColumnName("id")
                .HasColumnType("varchar(36)");

            entity.Property(e => e.RoleId)
                .HasColumnName("roleId")
                .HasColumnType("varchar(36)");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Role)
                .WithMany(p => p.User)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.RoleId)
                .HasConstraintName("user_ibfk_1");
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out, this **reason** is the **Lazy Loading**.

The **fix** is to use **Include()**.

One more thing to mention is, I use

```
_context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Added;
_context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
_context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

whenever I add/update/delete an entity before the SaveChanges() method is called.

Not sure whether I need to do this every time? Or the EF Core will be able to recognise it itself.

Answer (score 0):

SaveChanges won't populate navigation properties. It will populate PrimaryKeys (AutoIncremented integers for example) and ForeignKeys (if you had set the navigation properties before the SaveChanges) , but navigation properties themselves won't be set.